# oracle create type under type in java

Tags: java, oracle, types, sqlexception

I want make a Type

```
try {
    stmt.execute("CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE angestellte_t UNDER person_t (Name VARCHAR(20))");
}
catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

the Type `under_t` is not exist and `SQLException` is not called, but the type is created after this command in database and it shows (in database), that there are errors.

Can i see the errors while compiling in java?
Why it does not show `SQLException`?

Thanks

Comment: You really should re-read and re-write this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating PL/SQL objects doesn't throw an exception, the only indication that something went wrong is available through the warnings on the statement object.

So, after you run the DDL, use `stmt.getWarnings()` to see if there *were* any warnings. If `getWarnings()` returns something else than `null`, then something went wrong.

This corresponds to the message "*Warning: Type created with compilation errors*" that you would have gotten in SQL*Plus (if you call `SQLWarning.getMessage()` you actually get a similar message).

If there *was* a warning then the only way to retrieve the real error message is to query the view `ALL_ERRORS`  in your case you must run:

```
select line, position, text
from all_errors
where type = 'TYPE'
and name = 'ANGESTELLTE_T'
order by line;
```